# Google Maps API, Marker Clusterer limit

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

So i'm stumped with what looks like a file size limit using Google Maps API/Marker Clusterer; code for the full page below. This works absolutely fine for a JSON file of around 10000 records (the below code executes), but as soon as I go over that limit, to say a JSON file of 15000 the below code stop working. No markers/clusters are generated (i've waited in case it was browser perf issues). Anyone any ideas?

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="platform1.json"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="markerclusterer.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  function initialize() {

    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(36.597889,9.492188);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 3,center: center});

    var markers = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 10500; i++) {
      var dataGeo = data.geo[i];
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataGeo.LatAdj,dataGeo.LongAdj);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latLng,title: dataGeo.Title,org: dataGeo.Organisation});

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: " "});
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
      infowindow.setContent('<div class="mapTitle">'+this.title+", "+this.org+'</div>');
      infowindow.open(map, this);});

      markers.push(marker);
    }

    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: This may be an issue unrelated to your data set but with cis.gstati.com, use the chrome debugger and watch the network resources you will see when using the maps often googles static content gets stuck in large content.

Comment: I would look carefully at your data and verify that there isn't a required field missing.  Are you getting javascript errors?

Comment: I have the same issue when I use daily MAX temps for certain areas as the data set went up. I did not have the same issue when I used the HEATMAP and same data.  I think its the static data images that is the issue.

Comment: geocodezip; nope, data is good. I verified this by copying 'good' data (that clustered) then simply repeating it up to the 10000 limit, at which point the same issue occurred. alexmac, i'm gonna try a heatmap next as well...

Comment: OK, so running the developer network resources, something screwy is going on with the json file. This is the output of the developer console: platform.json 
Method:GET, Status: 500, Type: text/html, Initiator: platform.html:23, Size: 241 B, Time: Pending, then this is the output of the good (smaller) file: platform2.json, Method: GET, Status: 200, Type: text/html, Initiator: platform2.html:23, Size: 1.3 MB, Time: 209 ms ,any ideas anyone?

Comment: OK, so I've partially solved this, but it's messy and slow...i've split the 70000 record JSON file into batches of 14500 (this appears to be the arbitrary limit), essentially 5 different JSON files processed concurrently, then appended to the markers array. This works fine in Chrome, but not IE. Curse my world.